# Questions and clarifications needed concerning the definitions of equalizer and coequalizer in the category of vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory, notation, definition

The following is taken from *Fundamentals of Advanced Mathematics 1 : Categories, Algebraic Structures, Linear and Homological Algebra* by Henri Bourlès.

**Notations:**

Let ${_\mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{Vec}}$ denote the category of left vector spaces over the division ring $\mathbf{K}$, $\operatorname{eq}(f,g)$ the equalizer of a pair of arrows $f,g$, and $\operatorname{coeq}(f,g)$ the coequalizer of a pair of arrows $f,g$.

**Definitions for Equalizer and Coequalizer in ${_\mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{Vec}}$:**

*Equalizer*

Let $\mathcal{C}={_\mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{Vec}}$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a $\mathbf{K}$-linear function, we have $\operatorname{eq}(f,0)=\kappa:K\rightarrow A$ where $K=\ker(f):=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the definition of kernel of $f$ and $\kappa=\mathrm{can}$ is the canonical injection.

*Coequalizer*

Let $\mathcal{C}={_\mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{Vec}}$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a $\mathbf{K}$-linear function, we have $\operatorname{coeq}(f,0)=\gamma:B\rightarrow C$ where $C=B/\operatorname{im}(f)$ is the usual definition of the cokernel $\operatorname{coker}(f)$ of $f$ (with $\operatorname{im}(f)=f(A)$, the *image* of $A$ under $f$) and $\gamma=\mathrm{can}$ is the canonical surjection.

I have few quick questions related to the above two definitions.

1. Does the notation ${_\mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{Vec}}$ denoting left vector space mean that it is a vector space with only left multiplications?  I ask because of the following reasons, if we have $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ and $\kappa: K\rightarrow A$, then the equalizer of $f,g$ is $f\circ \kappa =g\circ \kappa,$ similarly, if we have again $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ and $\gamma:B\rightarrow C,$ then the coequalizer of $f,g$ is $\gamma \circ f=\gamma \circ g$.   In the case of equalizer, isn't $\kappa$ being left multiplied by $f$ and $g$ and similarly in the case of coequalizer, isn't $\gamma$ being right multiplied by both $f$ and $g$.
2. This is more notational, what does the notation $0$ mean in $(f,0)$.  We have $f,g:A\rightarrow B$, does $(f,0)$ mean $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g=0:A\rightarrow B$?   Also does $0:A\rightarrow B$ means that $g=0$ is either a zero map or a zero morphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category of vector spaces over non-commutative division ring $K$ is just a category of, i this case, left $K$-modules. In particular, this category is abelian. Abelian categories have in particular all the features you ask for:

They are $\mathrm{Ab}$-enriched, meaning that each hom-set has a canonical structure of abelian group, satisfying all coherence conditions. In particular, each group of homomorphism has a zero element. Moreover, each equaliser or coequaliser of two parallel arrows is equivalent to (co-)equaliser of their difference and the zero morphism. In general, the equaliser of two arrows $f, g$
$$Eq \rightarrow A\rightrightarrows B$$
Is such a morphism that every morphism $h: X \rightarrow A$ making the diagram commute, i.e. such that $gh = fh$ factors uniquely through $Eq$. Its easy to see, that in case of modules over a ring, equaliser of a pair $(f, g)$ is the kernel of $f-g$, and equivalently, equaliser of a pair $(f-g, 0)$. Similar idea lies behind coequalisers, this time with all the arrows reversed - every map $h: X \rightarrow B$ such that $hf = hg$ factors through $Coeq(f, g)$. Again, a direct argument shows that the quotient map $B \rightarrow B/im(f-g)$ satisfies precisely the necessery and sufficient condition of an coequaliser.

Going back to your first confusion about multiplication - indeed, a left module by definition is equipped only with left multiplication. Structures considered in practise often have structure of bimodules, where the multiplication from both sides is considered, however the bimodule structure is just the same as a left module over the ring $R \times R^{op}$, since left actions can be canonically identified with right actions of the opposite ring, with the same elements but multiplication done in reversed order. In case of division algebras opposite ring $R^{op}$ is canonically isomorphic to $R$, which need not be the case in general. However, do not confuse multiplication by a scalar, which comes from the module structure, with composition of arrows - clearly arrows can be composed on both sides, whatever it means.

--- EDIT --- (more on kernels and cokernels)

The abstract nonsense definition of kernels and cokernels can be done as follows:

Given additive category $\mathcal C$, (by definition) the hom functor takes values in abelian groups. Defining the kernel of abelian group homomorphism as usual, we can then use it to define kernels in $\mathcal C$ using induced homomorphism on representable functors, which in the spirit of Yoneda representing the objects of $\mathcal C$. Formally, at first we construct the kernel functor $\operatorname{Ker}(f): \mathcal C^{op} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ab}$

$$
\operatorname{Ker}(f)(-) = \operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{Hom}(-, X) \xrightarrow{\circ f} \operatorname{Hom}(-, Y))
$$

After translating the problem to abelian groups by (enriched in abelian groups) representable functors, in the same way we go back, defining the kernel object $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ as representing kernel functor, so such that we have a natural isomorphism of functors

$$
\operatorname{Ker}(f)(-) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(-, \operatorname{ker}(f))
$$

The definition may seem abstract, but it's just Yoneda lemma in enriched version applied twice to reduce the problem to category with already established solution. Similarly we treat cokernels, which are just kernels in the opposite category, i.e. $\operatorname{coker}(f) = (\operatorname{ker}(f^{op}))^{op}$

In this setting we can also define the image of $f: X \rightarrow Y$ as
$$
\operatorname{im}(f) = \operatorname{ker}(Y \rightarrow \operatorname{coker}(f))
$$

and coimage as
$$
\operatorname{coim}(f) = \operatorname{coker}(\operatorname{ker}(f) \rightarrow X)
$$

One version of defining abelian categories is to require all the image of coimages to exist and being naturally isomorphic.

In case of categories such as modules or vector spaces, we easily see that these definitions agree with what we know - for example the cokernel being a quotient of $Y$ by the image means exactly that the image is the kernel of the quotient map.

Comment: when you say "Similar idea lies behind equalisers, this time with all the arrows reversed..."  did you mean coequalizers instead?  Also if the definitions holds for left R-module, I can assume that the same definition goes through for right R-module and similarly for vector spaces over a field, finite or non-finite is that correct?  This is what I am taking from your answer.

Comment: Obviously, thanks for spotting that

Comment: I should have been even more specific, the definition goes through if we assume commutativity.  I don't think i really want to think about any potential mess that non commutativity can dredge up.

Comment: In case of commutative modules left and right multiplication just coincide, so there is no need to distinguish them

Comment: I just want to clarify, commutativity algebraic structure, in the context of category of specific algebraic structures, groups, rings, vector spaces, modules, algebras, etc, assuming commutativity is the same as saying they are part of something call an "Abelian" category?  I often hear this term on here.  Also, if you don't mind me asking, when i see the notation $(f,0)$, for $(f,g)$ in the case of parallel arrows, i am a bit confused over what $(f-g,0)$ is suppose to be for the $0$ map, i mean do I replace $(f,g)$ with $(f, f-g)$, but that doesn't seem to be what you meant.

Comment: Commutativity does not provide the structure of abelian categories. In fact, the only abelian categories that comes from algebraic theories are modules. Abelian category satisfies 3 condition: 1) its pre-additive, meaning that hom functors have values in abelian groups. This is not the case for all commutative structures, for example homomorphism of rings does not have well defined multiplication, as we require them to fix the unit. Moreover, we require Abelian categories to have zero element, both initial and terminal, which implies also that finite products and coproducts coincide.

Comment: Finally, we require them to have all the kernels and cokernels, and every monomorphism can be associated to some kernel. Similarly every epimorphism is a cokernel. This last axiom exclude such categories as topological abelian groups, where isomorphic groups with different topologies make same problems.

Comment: I am trying to decipher when you say that the " equaliser of a pair $(,)$ is the kernel of $−,$ and equivalently, equaliser of a pair $(−,0).$  How did you get from $\text{ker\{f-g\}}$ to $(f-g,0)$?

Comment: It just follows from the fact that $f(x) = g(x)$ iff $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, so properties of equalisers of f and g and f-g and 0 are identical

Comment: Obviously that's one of the features of abelian categories, as in general case we cannot add morphisms together, nor have specified the zero morphism.

Comment: does the same: $f(x)=g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)=0$ apply for the case of coequalizers too?  Or does that case requires more work because it requires one to quotient out stuff?  Actually, isn't $f(x)=g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)=0$ some sort of equivalence relations for equalizers?  Also, $f(x)=g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)=0$ this reminds me of what happens in category of Sets.

Comment: is pre-additive the same thing as additive category?  I am using Arbib and manes' text, I only seen additive categories so far in later chapters.  So can Abelian categories be additive as one of its conditions?

Comment: The additive category is a pre-additive one having the zero object, however on some sources the definitions can slightly differ. Abelian categories are precisely additive plus conditions on kernels and cokernels mentioned above

Comment: In case of coeqalisers the same reasonong happens, since it's property relies on relation $h\circ f = h\circ g$. So again, since $h\circ f = h\circ g$ if and only if $h\circ (f-g) = h\circ 0$, coequalisers of (f, g) and (f-g, 0) are isomorphic

Comment: the term of cokernel of a function, I know that for kernel of a function, it usually means it sends elements of the function to either the zero element or the identity element depending on the algebraic structure one is talking about.   What does the cokernel mean in the case of many algebraic structures or in the context of category theory.  I am guess for the case of coequalizer, it means it sends the element of function composition to zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer seems to have useful information here.

Comment: I added some abstract nonsense approach to kernels and cokernels, I hope that will answer your questions

Comment: @AlexanderGolys thank you for your added comments in your answer.  I just saw this now on my email.  In terms of set builder notation, if we have $f:X\rightarrow Y$, then $\text{ker}(f)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\}.$    As for cokernel of $f$ is the kernel of $f^{op}$ where $f^{op}$ is the opposite morphism$f^{op}:Y\rightarrow X$, and $\text{coker}(f)=\text{ker}(f^{op})=\{y\in Y\mid f^{op}(y)=0\}.$ I also read that $\text{coker}(f)=B/\text{im}(f)=B/f(A),$ where $f(A)=\{f(a):a\in A\}.$ But since $\text{im}(f)$ is meant to denote an equivalence relation defined...

Comment: @AlexanderGolys ... on $B$, then would $\text{coker}(f-g)=B/\text{im}(f-g)=B/(f-g)(A),$ where $(f-g)(A)=\{(f-g)(a):a\in A\}=\{f(a)-g(a)\mid a\in A\}.$  I did not use the $f^{op}$ notation here since I am just referring to the definition referenced in my post.